# Converting Multiple Time-series Signals into One Spectrogram

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science, computer-science, frequency

Is it possible to combine multivariate time series signals (from the same event) and convert them to the frequency domain to feed a spectrogram?  I would like to convert these signals to the frequency domain so that I can perform a Convolutional Neural Network and predict classifications of events.

So far, I've only seen examples using just ONE (1) time series, not multidimensional. Such as pictured here below.

[Time Series to Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS6HH.png)
[image]

As an example, let's assume (in the figure below) this is the data I collected in multiple time series for 1 day in the year. I've collected similar data for 30 other days. I want to combine the signals in a way to create a frequency spectrogram.

[Multivariate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVpTT.png)
[image]
**Can this be done? What are some ways to perform this operation?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the code/github link of that one time series conversion

Comment: Please leave messages like this for the comments section, and not answers

Comment: The picture was sourced from MathWorks demo. Link: https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/feature-extraction.html